# Web site in pure PHP with clean URL

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have enabled mod_rewrite in my Xampp Apache. When I run my `phpinfo()` page, I saw mod_rewrite under Loaded Modules. So I think it's enabled.

Then I create a folder clean-url under htdocs. Inside clean-url folder I have 3 files

1) index.php here I put

`<A href="test">Welcome</a>`

2) Test. php

3) .htaccess

Here I put

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

I want to run the index page, and by clicking on that hyper link I want to display the test.php page with URL

```
mydomain/clean-url/test
```

I know I am in a wrong path. What am I doing wrong? Also I don't know any idea about URL rewriting and .htaccess.

Comment: How did you create the .htaccess file? Are other rewrite rules working for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think you shouldn't use /$1/$2.php, just simply /$2.php

because you ask the rewrite to access the folder clean-url and open test.php in that folder.

try

```
^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

and see how it works ... then you should format in more complex regex.

Comment: Thanks. But still it's not working. I got teh error "object Not found..  Error 404"

Comment: i didn't get it, where is the .htaccess file? in the clean-url folder?

index.php hwre is it, i can't understand the file tree

Comment: .htaccess file is inside the clean-url folder
htdocs->clean-url->
index.php
.htaccess
.test.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a dash in `clean-url`, but your regex does not recognize it.

Change your `.htaccess` to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

and place it in `htdocs/` instead of `htdocs/clean-url/`.